# Is it possible to include a [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:] in a NSCompoundPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

I'm trying to make a big filter with a `NSCompoundPredicate` that includes a BlockPredicate but I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Problem with subpredicate BLOCKPREDICATE(0x19189b60)'
```

Each predicate by separated run very well, I have tried to make a first filter with all my normal predicates in a `NSCompoundPredicate` and then filter the array with the `BlockPredicate` and it run.

But my question is: is it possible to combine both in a NSCompoundPredicate?

Comment: Are you doing a filter on a CoreData base? If YES, predicate with Block aren't allowed in CoreData fetches. It's due to the "impossible" translation to SQL-like requests.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. Thanks!